# pyjwt decode method return Signature verification failed

Tags: python, pyjwt

A correct working token causes a decoding error using [pyjwt](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jwt/api_jwt.py", line 129, in decode
    decoded = self.decode_complete(jwt, key, algorithms, options, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jwt/api_jwt.py", line 100, in decode_complete
    decoded = api_jws.decode_complete(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py", line 182, in decode_complete
    self._verify_signature(signing_input, header, signature, key, algorithms)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py", line 269, in _verify_signature
    raise InvalidSignatureError("Signature verification failed")
jwt.exceptions.InvalidSignatureError: Signature verification failed
```

Method [decode](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=decode#jwt.decode)

**code.py**

```
    token = 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6Imdvb2dsZV9wYW5lbCIsInNjb3BlcyI6e30sImV4cGlyZV90aW1lIjoxNjY2ODA4NzYxLjE5OTIzNH0.ywGoByIbXA_9DGFzMUWF7fpu1P-Ab8lWOv8FiEhIczw'

class CustomAPI:    
    def _check_expire(self, token: str, key: str) -> str:
            try:
                jwt.decode(token, key, algorithms=['HS256'])
            except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
                token = self._get_authorize_token()
            return token
    
    
CustomAPI()._check_expire(token, settings.SECRET_KEY)
```

I saw a similar question and it suggested using `b64decode` for the `key` parameter

```
_check_expire(token, b64decode(settings.SECRET_KEY))
```

But the result is same

UPD

```
 key = 'h^z13$qr_s_wd65@gnj7a=xs7t05$w7q8!x_8zsld#'
```

I tried to use random string, but it didn't help

Comment: There isn't much to do wrong in one call to jwt.decode. Can you share the secret, so that I could check it? Besides that, the "expire_time": 1666808761.199 looks odd, I doubt that jwt.decode even recognizes that. The corrrect claim is "exp" with a Unix timestamp in seconds.

Comment: @jps I updated the question. About `expire_time` - I get it from a third party service, I can't affect it

Comment: Hm, it looks like it's really about the token itself, not the key

Comment: I checked it on jwt.io. This signature can't be verified with the given secret. Base64 decoding isn't an option, because it's not valid Base64. Nothing we can do here. But a remark regarding your expire_time: the  `jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:` exception won't ever get raised.  `jwt.decode()` will ignore the given expire_time, because it's a custom claim. You would need to write your own code for it.